# Construct Html string based on a simple string

Tags: php, html

I know how to use `str_replace(' ', '<span></span>', $text);`

But is there any way I can get a result like

```
cat, dog, elephant, pig
```

to be converted like

```
<span class="tagstyle">cat</span><span class="tagstyle">dog</span><span class="tagstyle">elephant</span><span class="tagstyle">pig</span>
```

Either in PHP, jQuery is it possible to replace comma separated value like a span method?

Comment: in php `echo '<span class="tagstyle">' . implode('</span><span class="tagstyle">', explode(',','cat, dog, elephant, pig ')) . '</span>';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP it could be:

```
<?php

$string = 'cat, dog, elephant, pig';
$animals = explode(',', $string);
$output = '';

foreach ($animals as $animal) {
    $output .= '<span class="tagstyle">' . trim($animal) . '</span>';
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$.map()` to translate the array to our required format, then join that array with empty string,

```
var str = "cat,dog,elephant,pig";
var htmlString = $.map(str.split(','),
    function(val,i){ 
     return '<span class="tagstyle">'+ val + '</span>'; 
}).join('');  //<span class="tagstyle">cat</span> .......
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9e7Yj/)

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
var animals = "cat, dog, elephant, pig";
var temp = animals.split(',');
var html = '';
$.each(temp, function (index, item) {
    console.log(item);
    html += '<span class="tagstyle">' + item + '</span>';

})

$("#contain").html(html);
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/MSfJ9/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just simple like that, you can try:

```
'<span class="tagstyle">'.str_replace(', ','</span><span class="tagstyle">',$text).'</span>';
```

or

```
$array = explode(', ',$text);
$newText = '<span class="tagstyle">'.implode('</span><span class="tagstyle">',$array).'</span>';
```